# Return first element occurring at a particular frequency

Tags: clojure

For fun, I'm using Peter Norvig's Udacity CS212 course (taught in python) as a vehicle for learning some Clojure.

In said course, he has a function that returns the first element of a sequence that occurs at a specified frequency:

```
def kind(n, ranks):
    """Return the first rank that this hand has
    exactly n-of-a-kind of. Return None if there
    is no n-of-a-kind in the hand."""
    for r in ranks:
        if ranks.count(r) == n: return r
    return None
```

I've figured out how to do this as a one-liner in clojure, but what a frightening one-liner it is:

```
(defn n-of-kind
  [n ranks]
  "Detect whether a hand rank contains n of a kind, returning first
  rank that contains exactly n elements"
  (first (keys (into {} (filter #(= (second %) n) (frequencies ranks))))))

(n-of-kind 3 [5 5 5 3 3]) ;; correctly returns 5
```

My intuition is that there has to be a Better Way. The frequencies function is very useful, but the remainder of this code is simply searching for a value and returning its key. If the frequencies function had returned a map with the frequencies as the key rather than the values I could do something like ((frequencies ranks) n).

Can anyone suggest a more readable / concise way of doing this?

Comment: You can use clojure.set/map-invert to swap keys and values, but that wouldn't help much here because if multiple keys map to the same value it only preserves one of them. Also, note that any solution that relies on a map risks losing the ordering of the sequence.

Comment: BTW, as far as one-liners in Clojure go, I've seen much worse! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another version

```
(defn n-of-kind [n ranks]
  (first (filter #(= n (count (filter #{%} ranks)))
                 ranks)))
```

Comment: I think this is the only one that meets the "first element in the sequence" part of the requirements since it retains the order of ranks.

Comment: This is a good point. My initial version doesn't retain the ordering of the elements. I suppose for the purposes of the larger program (poker hand scoring), one could also make the decision to return the *largest* rank, or better, all ranks from which one could later select the max and min (for the case of two pair). But this more directly answers the question asked. Will wait a bit to see if any other suggestions come in, but this is certainly more correct than my version.

Answer (score 1):

you can reverse a map by building a new map using the values as keys and the keys as values:

```
(zipmap (vals my-map) (keys my-map))
```

Using a map from frequencies to keys is easy enough, and solves the original problem, though it runs into the problem of items occurring the same number of times disappearing because the second count of them clobbers the first:

```
user> (def data (take 20 (repeatedly #(rand-nth [:a :b :c :d :e :f]))))
#'user/data
user> (let [f (frequencies data)] (zipmap (vals f) (keys f)))
{1 :f, 3 :d, 4 :c}
user> (frequencies data)
{:e 4, :b 4, :a 4, :d 3, :c 4, :f 1}
```

if you instead start with a list of maps from frequencies to sets of keys with that frequency then reduce that down to a single map of sets then no data is lost though the code is a bit bigger:

```
user> (reduce (partial merge-with clojure.set/union) 
        (let [f (frequencies data)] 
          (map hash-map (vals f) (map hash-set (keys f)))))

{1 #{:f}, 3 #{:d}, 4 #{:a :c :b :e}}
```